# Redirecting console (or stdout) to named pipe no longer works when compiling with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio, console, named-pipes, stdio

I have a scripting engine which redirects its stdout to a named pipe for debugging purposes. The code below has been working since Visual Studio 6, but no longer seems to work at all when compiling with VS2015. No errors are thrown, but the output continues to be written to the console instead of the named pipe. When I compile this application in VS2012, it works as expected.

hNamedPipe is the pipe I want to redirect console text to.

```
int hCrt = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hNamedPipe, _O_TEXT);
FILE *hf = _fdopen(hCrt, "w");
*stdout = *hf;
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

How might I redirect stdio to a named pipe when compiling with the Visual C++ v14 platform tool-set?

Comment: Not sure, but modifying `stdout` like this looks fishy, I suppose it worked "by chance" in the older versions.

Comment: This looks like something you should use [`freopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen) for.

Comment: The freopen() with "conout$" also works pre-visual studio 2015.

Comment: Also, there are other MS connect feedback items regarding changes in this area: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1279133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to James McNellis I was able to arrive at a solution:

> This is by design. FILE is an opaque data type; you are not allowed to
>   dereference a FILE as you have done in your code.

This is the code which ultimately worked for me:

```
void main()
{
    HANDLE hNamedPipe = Create_Some_Named_Pipe();

    RedirectIO(stdout, hNamedPipe);
    printf("Hello World."); //This arrived at the listening named pipe.
}

void RedirectIO(FILE *hFrom, HANDLE hTo)
{
    int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hTo, _O_WRONLY | _O_TEXT);
    _dup2(fd, _fileno(hFrom));
    setvbuf(hFrom, NULL, _IONBF, 0); //Disable buffering.
}
```

Comment: Be careful with the `_fileno`, the documentation says it can return negative number and it does if a standard handle is already closed (parent proces has called CreateProcess w/o standard handles inheritance). You must use direct number, for example, `STDOUT_FILENO` instead of `_fileno(stdout)`, otherwise all sequenced calls will fail, which means `_close(fd)` will close the handle w/o a duplication!